# How to use machine ip address with https to run / host dotnet core application using Kestrel(Without IIS)

Tags: .net-core, kestrel-http-server

*How to use machine IP address ( https://192.168.1.102:5001) instead of localhost (https://localhost:5000) to host/run dotnet core application using Kestrel(Without IIS):*

I am using the following configuration

```
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
        {
            serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
            serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, 
                listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps("cert.pfx", 
                        "123");
                });
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

I know we can use **.UseUrls("http://192.168.0.101:5001")** as follows, but this does not work with **https**

```
 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.
                    UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://192.168.0.101:5001")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration().UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Any suggestion or guide would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess it's the wrong IP.
Try use this: go to cmd => ipconfig => Ethernet adapter Ethernet => IPv4 Address

Comment: Hmm , Actually this is the correct IPv4 address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the silly mistake I was making.

I had to pass ip address as follows:

```
serverOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.101"), 5001, ....
```